# How to grep two words in string data?

Tags: r

So I have a data frame where the one of the columns is of type character, consisting of strings. I want to find those rows where "foo" and "bar" both occur but bar can also occur before foo. Basically like an AND operator for regular expressions. How shall I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
 rowIndx <- grepl('foo', df$yourcol) & grepl('bar', df$yourcol)
```

`rowIndx` returns a logical `TRUE/FALSE` which can be used for subsetting the col. (comments from @Konrad Rudolph).  If you need the numeric index, just wrap it with `which` i.e. `which(rowIndx)`

Comment: The `which` is usually unnecessary: the result is probably going to be used to index a table anyway.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Thanks

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought the OP wanted the row index

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are bad at logical operations. Your particular case, however, can be trivially implemented by the following expression:

```
(foo.*bar)|(bar.*foo)
```

However, this is a very inefficient regex and I strongly advise against using it. In practice, you’d use akrun’s solution from the comment: `grep` for them individually and intersect the result (or do a logical `grepl` and `&` the results, which is semantically exchangeable).